# Linux Apache2 Wordpress core in subdirectory but no redirect to wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

My current Wordpress installation is located in `/var/www/html/mydomain.tld/cms/` and my WP_SITEURL is set to `https://mydomain.tld/cms` and WP_HOME to `https://mydomain.tld` in the wp-config.php.

In `/var/www/html/mydomain.tld/index.php` I have `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/cms/wp-blog-header.php' );`.
`/var/www/html/mydomain.tld/.htaccess` has the following code:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

The `/var/www/html/mydomain.tld/.htaccess` is empty.
My permalink is set to "day and name": `https://mydomain.tld/2018/06/02/sample-post/`.

The current behavior is that I can browse using `https://mydomain.tld` and pages like `https://mydomain.tld/about` work without any problems.

The issue is that I put the wordpress installation in a subdirectory to make sure `https://mydomain.tld/wp-admin` will return a 404. But right now it returns a 302 pointing to `https://mydomain.tld/cms/wp-admin` effectively redirecting any attacker to the right place.

How can I configure my wordpress and/or Apache2 to behave the way intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have mod_alias you can

Redirect 404 /wp-admin/

As in throw 404 on that url

Taken from https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42822/how-to-redirect-specific-url-to-404-in-htaccess

I have not tried it yet.

Comment: Adding `Redirect 404 /wp-admin` and `Redirect 404 /wp-login.php` to the end of the .htaccess of the site worked! Thank you very much.